# Is photoelectric effect example of inelastic collision

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

I was reading photoelectric effect , which was completely explained by Einstein. And a bit difficult question , atleast seems to me is whether photoelectric effect is inelastic collision or elastic collision . Every where it is written that photoelectric effect is example of inelastic collision . But as far as I know  in inelastic collision some energy become internal energy of the system , there maybe some energy loss as heat or something . But here in photoelectric effect photon is being absorbed by electron but where is the energy loss? No energy is being lost here the energy $h\nu $  is absorbed by electron and its kinetic energy increases so no energy loss occurs . So in my opinion it is not an inelastic collision . So what is the reality , is it inelastic or elastic collision ?

Comment: What about the work function ? Some energy of $h\nu$ is used up there ...

Comment: But how can you say that this energy  is lost ? It actually increases electron's energy . So energy conserves

Comment: Energy is not lost rather used up as work function.

Comment: Then how can we say that energy is not being conserved ?

Comment: Energy is still conserved ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a photon interacts with an atom, three things can happen:

1. elastic scattering, when the photon keeps its energy, and changes angle
2. inelastic scattering, when the photon gives part of its energy to the atomic  system and changes angle
3. absorption, when the photon gives all its energy to the atom, and the valence electron will move to a higher energy level, and then the electron will eventually move back to a lower energy level and emit a photon

At low energies, Rayleigh scattering happens, 1. elastic.

In your case, photo electricity is when 3. happens. That is at higher energies.

At even higher energies, 2. happens, Compton scattering.

Comment: So is it elastic or inelastic collision ?

Comment: Basically none, it is absorption and re-emission.

Answer (score 0):

Photoelectric effect is an example of inelastic collision as we know that photon transfer it's all energy to electron but electron emit with kinetic energy smaller than the energy of photon as some energy is absorbed as work function Hence it is the example of inelastic collision

Comment: While this answer is correct, what's the point of mostly repeating part of the answer that was already accepted?